# Symfony 3.4: NumberType & MoneyType are rendering text type html input instead of number type input

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfony 3.4 and I get an issue with NumberType Form Field which is rendering a text input:

## ElementArrivageType.php:

```
->add('prixUnit', NumberType::class, array(
  'scale' => 3,
  'attr' => array(
    "min" => 0,
    "scale" => 3,
    "step" => 0.001,
    "placeholder" => "0.000",
  )
))
```

## Twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.prixUnit, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

## Result F12:

```
<input type="text" id="appbundle_arrivage_elementArrivages_2_prixUnit" name="appbundle_arrivage[elementArrivages][2][prixUnit]" required="required" min="0" scale="3" step="0.001" placeholder="0.000" class="form-control prixUnit" value="500.011">
```

When documenting I found a Solution that doesn't worked for me :

## Twig :

```
{% block number_widget %}
    <div class="number_widget">
        {% set type = type|default('number') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The only solution that I found is a not clean solution:

```
//forcing type when loading DOM:
$('#appbundle_arrivage_elementArrivages_2_prixUnit').prop('type', 'number');
```

Does anyone have a clean solution ?

Comment: You asked the same question 2 days ago, please don't delete and post same question again.

Comment: Please link your entity

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's resolved by Form Functions and Variables Reference:

```
{{ form_row(form.price, {'type': 'number'}) }}
```

Documented here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template

Answer (score 1):

You can now add the [html5](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#html5) option:

> html5 type: boolean default: false
>
> If set to true, the HTML input will be rendered as a native HTML5
> type="number" form.

```
->add('prixUnit', NumberType::class, array(
  'scale' => 3,
  'attr' => array(
    "min" => 0,
    "scale" => 3,
    "step" => 0.001,
    "placeholder" => "0.000",
  ),
  'html5' => true,
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Symfony's documentation:

> Renders an input text field and specializes in handling number input.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/number.html

So it's ok if you have a text input. Symfony will, on submit, check if it's a number and not a string

Comment: Thank you of course I know that but while taping it allows me to write all 
non numeric characters!!

Comment: Yes but on submit your form will not be valid and the user will have to change the value to validate the form.

Comment: Yes, I'm searching for a clean way to apply a mask to an input without causing form invalidate like 12000 => 12 000 in the front and when submitted it must accept it as a number